# Existence of an element that preserves the norm of a countable set

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces

Let $X$ be a (real) infinite-dimensional Banach space and $\{x_n\}_n\subset X$ a sequence. Does there exists some $x\in X\setminus\{0\}$ such that
$$\|x_n+x\|\ge\|x_n\|\text{ for all }n\text{ ?}$$
My intuition tells me that the answer is positive since the cardinality of any Hamel basis in $X$ must be uncountable, hence it does not metter how you pick a countable set $\{x_n\}_n$, you will always be able to find an element $x$ that lies in a different linear subspace from the linear span of the $x_n$'s, i.e. from
$$\bigcup_n\text{Span}\{x_1,\ldots,x_n\}.$$
However I'm not able to prove it. Can anyone prove it/give a reference if it is a well known result, or give a counterexample if I'm wrong?

Comment: I don‘t have a proof, but my intuition suggest this not being true. I think of a sequence in $X=\mathbb{R}^2$ which goes around the origin in ascending radii, like a spiral. Then whatever $x\in X$ you take, there will be some point in your sequence, i.e. a point on some circle with large radius (larger then the norm of $x$), which gets closer to the origin after adding $x$ to it - maybe this works as a counter-example...?

Comment: I did not specify it, but it should have been clear from my explanation that i'm considering infinite-dimensional Banach spaces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, no: in point of fact, let $X$ be a separable Banach space and let $\{x_n\}_{n\in\Bbb N}$ be a sequence with dense image. Then, for all $x\ne 0$ there will be some subsequence $x_{n_k}\to -x$. For said subsequence, eventually as $k\to\infty$ $$\left\lVert x_{n_k}\right\rVert\ge \frac12\lVert -x\rVert=\frac12\lVert x\rVert$$ and $$\left\lVert x_{n_k}+x\right\rVert<\frac15\lVert x\rVert$$

Comment: This is true. But for the non-separable case do you think this could happen?

Comment: @steCiacco I don't know, actually. I have a couple of ideas, but I can see hem going either way. Perhaps I'll investigate them when I'm less tired.